# Android Eclipse - how to include just Google Maps in project, instead of entire Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Google Play Services is taking about 30K method count, while I am using just Google maps. Please let me know how I can include just Google Maps in my project, instead of the entire Play Services lib.

I am using Eclipse. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You should go with *Android Studio* for particular *dependency* use. As *eclipse* will not support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [on this link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), you can use `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1` in your gradle file.

> In versions of Google Play services prior to 6.5, you had to compile
>   the entire package of APIs into your app. In some cases, doing so made
>   it more difficult to keep the number of methods in your app (including
>   framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536
>   limit.
>
> From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play
>   service APIs into your app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is this possible in Eclipse too ? I am using Eclipse, and not able to figure out the equivalent of this approach.

Comment: There is no equivalent for Eclipse. Eclipse has been deprecated for years.

Comment: I'd encourage you to start moving your projects to Android Studio. Moving a medium size app should take you maybe 1 day (including installing all the tools) but it's worth it.

Comment: Understood. I will do that, thanks to everyone for prompt help.